# try to connect to mysql through command line , leaves blank space after password

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to connect to an rds mysql server from an ec2 ubuntu server.

I use

```
mysql -h my_host_name -u admin_name -p database < data.sql
```

When the password prompts, I enter my password. However all this does it create a new blank line and does nothing else.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try using semicolon ";"

Comment: What kind of queries are in `data.sql`? Unless it has `SELECT` queries, this won't produce any output.

Answer (score 1):

When `mysql` is processing file input, it doesn't normally print informative messages, it only displays the results of `SELECT` queries. If you want to see messages from queries that modify the database, add the `-v` option to make it verbose.

```
mysql -v -h my_host_name -u admin_name -p database < data.sql
```

If you use `-v -v` it will produce even more details, and `-v -v -v` will be most informative.

Answer (score 0):

This blank line probably means that your mysql is processing what is inside your "data.sql". 
If you need to see what is been processed, you can first connect to mysql server with:

```
mysql -h my_host_name -u admin_name -p
```

Change to your database ( if you have one defined and your sql is not creating one... ):

```
mysql> change my_database;
```

Than you call your script execution with:

```
mysql> source data.sql;
```

{}'s